Parent Chart deploying sub-charts with multiple values
I am trying to look for a way to keep my helm charts DRY, but not end up with a values file that is impossible to navigate (3000+ lines), and have the sub-charts deployed via a parent chart.
My current folder structure example is as such:
charts/
┣ 0-commons/
┃ ┣ templates/
┃ ┣ Chart.yaml
┃ ┗ values.yaml
┣ app1/
┃ ┣ templates/
┃ ┃ ┣ subchart-resource/
┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ resource-extra1.yaml
┃ ┃ ┣ _envVarsHelper.tpl
┃ ┃ ┣ _helpers.tpl
┃ ┃ ┣ deployment.yaml
┃ ┃ ┣ hpa.yaml
┃ ┃ ┣ service.yaml
┃ ┣ Chart.yaml
┃ ┣ values-special.yaml
┃ ┗ values.yaml
┣ app2/
┃ ┣ templates/
┃ ┃ ┣ subchart-resource/
┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ resource-extra1.yaml
┃ ┃ ┣ _envVarsHelper.tpl
┃ ┃ ┣ _helpers.tpl
┃ ┃ ┣ deployment.yaml
┃ ┃ ┣ hpa.yaml
┃ ┃ ┣ service.yaml
┃ ┣ Chart.yaml
┃ ┣ values-special.yaml
┃ ┗ values.yaml
...
┣ parent-chart/
┃ ┣ templates/
┃ ┃ ┣ _helpers.tpl
┃ ┣ Chart.yaml
┃ ┣ values-production.yaml
┃ ┣ values-staging.yaml
┃ ┣ values-uat.yaml
┃ ┗ values.yaml

Im trying to keep everything DRY as the app charts are exactly the same apart from the values.yaml and values-special.yaml.
What i am trying to do is create a "common" chart for all sub-charts to use, and get my parent-chart to deploy them all out.
I would need a seperate values.yaml and values-special.yaml for each sub-chart, which i know i can specify as values-app1.yaml and values-app1-special.yaml etc.
Would there be a way to tell my helm chart to deploy a list of apps like you can with dependencies in the Chart.yaml normally? Something like:
apiVersion: v2
name: parent-chart
description: A parent chart
type: application
version: 0.0.1
appVersion: "0.0.1"
dependencies:
  - name: app1
    repository: "file://../0-commons"
    values: ../path/to/values-app1.yaml
  - name: app2
    repository: "file://../0-commons"
    values: ../path/to/values-app2.yaml

And when deploying the parent chart, you can just use:
helm upgrade --install parent-chart repo/chart --values values-<ENV>.yaml

Ideally, the new folder structure would be something like:
charts/
┣ 0-commons/
┃ ┣ templates/
┃ ┃ ┣ subchart-resource/
┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ resource-extra1.yaml
┃ ┃ ┣ _envVarsHelper.tpl
┃ ┃ ┣ _helpers.tpl
┃ ┃ ┣ deployment.yaml
┃ ┃ ┣ hpa.yaml
┃ ┃ ┣ service.yaml
┃ ┣ Chart.yaml
┃ ┗ values.yaml
┣ app1/
┃ ┣ values-special.yaml
┃ ┗ values.yaml
┣ app2/
┃ ┣ values-special.yaml
┃ ┗ values.yaml
...
┣ parent-chart/
┃ ┣ templates/
┃ ┃ ┣ _helpers.tpl
┃ ┣ Chart.yaml
┃ ┣ values-production.yaml
┃ ┣ values-staging.yaml
┃ ┣ values-uat.yaml
┃ ┗ values.yaml

Again, i would like to try and avoid adding the values of each sub-chart into the values-ENV.yaml of the parent chart as it would be a lot worse for DevEx, and maintaining as giant values would not be fun!
If not, is there a different/better way to do this?
Cheers in advance!

I've generally had bad experiences using a Helm umbrella chart to try to deploy multiple applications at the same time.  Its behaviors doing things like collapsing indirect dependencies and combining named templates can lead to conflicts and confusing behavior.  Can you use multiple helm install commands (maybe against the same underlying chart) to deploy this stack, or a purpose-built tool like Helmfile that does the same thing?

Hi David! Sadly i cant deploy without the umbrella chart. As this is a distributed monolith, there is a fair bit of coupling between the services, and the whole stack has to come up together. Ill have to have a look into helmfile to see if it is something that can do this, as ive never used it before :D
